# Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of complex functions analytic on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on the closed unit disc $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ such that

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \leq M < \infty.
$$

Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

---

It suffices to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded (for all $w \in \mathbb{D}$ there exists $\delta > 0$ and $M < \infty$ such that $|z - w| < \delta \implies |f(z)| < M$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$). We  believe that we should apply Cauchy's integral formula much like how [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611778/contour-integral-inequality-and-normal-families) suggests, but I do not believe that we can apply Cauchy's integral formula to $\partial\mathbb{D}$ since it is not contained in $\mathbb{D}$, the region in which all the functions are analytic. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: With notation as in the answer you link, use Cauchy's integral formula in $C_s$ with $s>r$, and the constant you get will be modified to $M/2\pi(s-r)$, but that's not a problem.

Comment: How would I eventually make the integral an integral over the boundary of the disc?

Comment: You can either take the limit as $s\to 1^-$ (using continuity of $f$, also the constant in my previous comment should be $M_{f,s}/2\pi(s-r)$), or use that the map $s\mapsto 1/2\pi \int_{C_s} |f(z)|\, d\sigma (z)$ for fixed $f$ is increasing in $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $f\in \mathcal{F}$ and let $g(s):=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(se^{it})|dt$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on the unit disk, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $1-\delta<s<1$, then $|f(z)-f(sz)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in \partial \mathbb D$. The reverse triangle inequality then gives $g(s)\to g(1)$ as $s\to 1^-$.

Fix two numbers $0<r<s<1$. By Cauchy's integral formula applied on the disk of radius $s$ we have, for any $|z|<r$,
$$
|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{|f(se^{it})|}{|z-se^{it}|}\, dt \leq \dfrac{g(s)}{(s-r)}.
$$
Keeping $z,r$ fixed, and letting $s\to 1^-$ we arrive at
$$
|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{M}{2\pi(1-r)}, \qquad |z|<r.
$$

Comment: Thanks Jose! We used this idea, but made some changes. We fixed $w \in \mathbb{D}$ then drew a ball of radius $r$ around it so that it's contained in $\mathbb{D}$. Then, we got a ball of radius $s$ centered at zero around the ball of radius $r$ to have $B_r(w) \subset B_s(0) \subset \mathbb{D}$. Then, basically everything you wrote applies, but we had a lower bound of $s - r - |w|$ in the integral instead of $s - r$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Cauchy's integral formula cannot be applied directly to the boundary of the unit disk, since the functions in F are only analytic on the interior of the disk.

However, we can use the fact that the functions in F are continuous on the boundary of the disk to bound their values on compact subsets of the disk. Specifically, for any w in D and any compact subset K of D containing w, we can choose a small disk B(w,δ) centered at w such that B(w,δ) is contained in K and δ is small enough that the closure of B(w,δ) is also contained in K. Since the functions in F are continuous on the closed unit disk, they are uniformly continuous on the closure of B(w,δ). Therefore, there exists a constant M<∞ such that |f(z)|<M for all z in the closure of B(w,δ) and all f in F.

Now, for any w in D, we can choose a compact subset K of D containing w, and choose a disk B(w,δ) as described above. Since K is compact, we can cover it with a finite number of such disks B(w1,δ), B(w2,δ), ..., B(wn,δ) with centers w1, w2, ..., wn. Then, for any z in K, there exists some wi such that |z - wi| < δ, and we have:

|f(z)| ≤ |f(z) - f(wi)| + |f(wi)|

By the uniform continuity of f on the closure of B(wi,δ), we can choose δ small enough that |f(z) - f(wi)| < ε/2 for all z in B(wi,δ). Then, using the bound on |f(wi)| derived above, we have:

|f(z)| ≤ ε/2 + M < ∞

for all z in K and all f in F. Therefore, F is locally uniformly bounded on D.

Note that this argument does not require the use of Cauchy's integral formula, but instead relies on the fact that the functions in F are continuous on the boundary of the unit disk.

Now that we have shown that F is locally uniformly bounded on D, we can use Montel's theorem to conclude that F is a normal family. Montel's theorem states that a family of holomorphic functions on a domain in the complex plane is normal if and only if it is locally uniformly bounded.

To apply Montel's theorem to our situation, we note that the functions in F are analytic on the open unit disk D, which is a domain in the complex plane. We have just shown that F is locally uniformly bounded on D, which implies that F is a normal family. Therefore, we have shown that the family F of complex functions analytic on the open unit disk D and continuous on the closed unit disk D¯¯¯¯ is a normal family.

we have shown that F is locally uniformly bounded on D by using the continuity of the functions in F on the boundary of the unit disk. This implies that F is a normal family by Montel's theorem.

As for theorem proved part:
To show that the family F is normal, we need to show that every sequence of functions in F has a uniformly convergent subsequence on compact subsets of D.

To start, let {fn} be any sequence of functions in F. We want to find a subsequence {fnk} that converges uniformly on any compact subset K of D.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have:

|f(e^(iθ))| ≤ 1/sqrt(2π) ∫_0^(2π) |f(e^(iφ))| dφ

for any f in F and any θ in [0,2π].

Using this inequality, we can bound the maximum value of |f| on any compact subset K of D:

|f(z)| ≤ sup{|z| ≤ r} |f(z)| ≤ sup{|z| ≤ r} (1/sqrt(2π) ∫_0^(2π) |f(e^(iφ))| dφ ) ≤ M(r)

where M(r) is a constant that depends only on the radius r of K.

Now, we can use Arzela-Ascoli theorem, which states that a family of functions that is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded is normal. We have already shown that the family F is pointwise bounded. To show equicontinuity, let ε > 0 and let δ = ε/2M(r), where M(r) is as defined above. Then, for any z1, z2 in K with |z1 - z2| < δ and any f in F, we have:

|f(z1) - f(z2)| ≤ |f(z1)| + |f(z2)| ≤ 2M(r)

Using the Cauchy integral formula, we can show that for any f in F, the sequence {fn} converges uniformly to f on any compact subset K of D as n approaches infinity:

|f - fn| ≤ sup{|z| ≤ r} |f(z) - fn(z)| ≤ sup{|z| ≤ r} 1/(2πi) ∫_C |(f(ζ) - fn(ζ))/(ζ - z)| dζ

where C is a circle centered at z with radius δ. Since δ depends only on ε and M(r), we can choose δ small enough such that the integral is less than ε/2 for all n > N, where N is a positive integer. Then, for n > N, we have:

|f - fn| ≤ ε/2 + ε/2 = ε

This shows that the sequence {fn} converges uniformly to f on K as n approaches infinity. Since {fn} is an arbitrary sequence in F, we have shown that F is normal.

Therefore, we have proved that the family F is normal.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).